Planes attached point by point produce plane bundles
The issues I met came from quaternionic functions, but since the algebra is not involved I would rephrase it considering only the linear structure $\mathbb{R}^4$ or $\mathbb{R}^8$. I would like to know if the following two constructions produce vector bundles.
Firstly, let us represents vector in $\mathbb{R}^8$ in two ways: $x=(x_0,\dots,x_7)$, with $x_j\in\mathbb{R}$ or $x=(x_0,\mathbf{x},y_0,\mathbf{y})$, with $x_0,y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x,y}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Now, consider the sets $$A:=\{(x_0,\dots,x_7)\in\mathbb{R}^8:x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\neq0\},$$ $$Q=\{(x_0,\mathbf{x},y_0,\mathbf{y})\in\mathbb{R}^8:y_0=0,\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0},\mathbf{x}\perp\mathbf{y}\}\subset A$$
and the map $$\pi_Q:A\to Q,\qquad (x_0,\mathbf{x},y_0,\mathbf{y})\in A\mapsto(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)\in Q,$$ where $\mathbf{y}^\perp$ is the component of $\mathbf{y}$ orthogonal (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) to $\mathbf{x}$, which by assumption is a non zero vector. In coordinates, if $x=(x_0,\dots,x_7)$, $\pi_Q(x)$ looks like
$$
\pi_Q(x):=\left(x_0,\dots,x_3,0,x_5-x_1\frac{x_1x_5+x_2x_6+x_3x_7}{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2},x_6-x_2\frac{x_1x_5+x_2x_6+x_3x_7}{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2},x_7-x_3\frac{x_1x_5+x_2x_6+x_3x_7}{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}\right).
$$
Note that $\pi_Q$ cannot be continuously extended to $\mathbb{R}^8$.
My main goal is to understand if $(\pi_Q,A,Q)$ is a vector bundle, in which the fibers are planes, consisting of the coordinate $x_4$ and the direction parallel to $\mathbf{x}$:
$$
A=\bigcup_{(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)\in Q}\{(x_0,\mathbf{x},\alpha,\mathbf{y}^\perp+\mathbf{b}):\alpha\in\mathbb{R},\mathbf{b}\in<\mathbf{x}>\}.
$$
There is another construction I would like to understand if produces a vector bundle:
$$
\pi_1:Q\to\mathbb{R}^4, (x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)\mapsto(x_0,\mathbf{x}).
$$
Maybe this is trivial, since looks more like a projection, but the fact is that the planes in the total space (this time $Q$ is the total space) vary depending on $\mathbf{x}$. Again, the fibers should be planes and
$$
Q=\bigcup_{(x_0,\mathbf{x})\in\mathbb{R}^4}\{(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{b}):\mathbf{b}\in<\mathbf{x}>^\perp\}.
$$
For this second construction there is something I already know, that can helps. Namely, consider $\mathbb{S}^2=\{(0,x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1\}$ and $$B=\{(x_0,\mathbf{x},y_0,\mathbf{y}):x_0,y_0=0,\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{S}^2,\mathbf{y}\in<\mathbf{x}>^\perp\}\subset Q.$$
Then $\pi_1:B\to\mathbb{S}^2$ is a vector bundle (more precisely, a tangent bundle). Maybe, the second construction can be deduced from the last one as a pull-back bundle of the stereographic projection $$p:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{S}^2,p(\mathbf{x})=\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right)?$$
Thank you for any help with this problem.
P.S. This question is linked to this one Projection that varies point by point is an open map

I am not sure if the following argument sufficies to prove the claims. In both cases I will pullback a vector bundle on $\mathbb{S}^2$, namely the normal bundle $N\mathbb{S}^2$ and the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{S}^2$. 
Let us start dealing with the second construnction $\pi_1:Q\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$. Consider the radial projection $p:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{S}^2$, $p(x_0,\mathbf{x})=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}$, then pull back $T\mathbb{S}^2$ via $p$:
$$
p^*T\mathbb{S}^2=(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})\times_{\mathbb{S}^2}T\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x_0,\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y},\eta)\in(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})\times T\mathbb{S}^2:p(x_0,\mathbf{x})=\pi_1(\mathbf{y},\eta)\}\\
=\{(x_0,\mathbf{x};\mathbf{y},\eta)\in(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})\times T\mathbb{S}^2:\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}=\mathbf{y}\}\\
=\left\{\left(x_0,\mathbf{x};\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|},\eta\right):(x_0,\mathbf{x})\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\},\mathbf{x}\perp\eta\right\},
$$
which is isomorphic to $Q$ by
$$
p^*T\mathbb{S}^2\ni\left(x_0,\mathbf{x};\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|},\eta\right)\mapsto (x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\eta)\in Q.
$$
For the second construction, consider again the radial projection (with a different domain) $p:Q\to\mathbb{S}^2$, $p(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}$, so the total space of the pullback bundle of $N\mathbf{S}^2$ via $p$ is
$$
p^*N\mathbb{S}^2=Q\times_{\mathbb{S}^2}N\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp;\mathbf{z},\mu):(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)\in Q, (\mathbf{z},\mu)\in N\mathbb{S}^2, p(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)=\pi_1(\mathbf{z},\mu)\}\\
=\left\{(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp;\mathbf{z},\mu):(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)\in Q, (\mathbf{z},\mu)\in N\mathbb{S}^2,\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}=\mathbf{z}\right\}\\
=\left\{\left(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp;\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|},\mu\right):(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)\in Q, \mu \in<\mathbf{x}>\right\},
$$
which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb{R}^3$ by
$$
p^*N\mathbb{S}^2\ni\left(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp;\frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|},\mu\right)\mapsto (x_0,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}^\perp+\mu)\in \mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb{R}^3.
$$
Finally the desired plane bundle over $Q$ is $\pi_Q:\mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb{R}^4\to Q$, $\pi_Q((x_0,\mathbf{x},y_0,\mathbf{y}^\perp+\mu))=(x_0,\mathbf{x},0,\mathbf{y}^\perp)$.
